Python Cross table count Issue
I'm trying to create a cross table in Python to count data based on specific bins for a data analysis task. My goal is to classify entries by distance and sample size categories based on thresholds, then count occurrences for each category combination. However, I’m encountering discrepancies between the expected and actual results.
I want to group my data by distance and store IDs, count occurrences in each bin, and generate a cross table that shows these counts. Below is the setup and code I’m using, along with an example dataset and the expected output.
Example dataset:
import pandas as pd

# Sample data for demonstration
data = {
    'distance': [15, 10, 5, 95, 50, 45, 120, 220, 240, 280, 300, 400, 800, 500, 600, 1000, 900, 700, 350, 150],
    'store_id': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4],
    'campaign_transaction_id': list(range(1, 21))
}
merged_data = pd.DataFrame(data)


Here is the Python code I used:
import pandas as pd

# Define bins for 'distance' and sample sizes
difference_bins = [0, 21, 101, 251, 100000000]
sample_bins = [1, 6, 11, 21, 51, 201]

# Create categorical columns based on bins
merged_data['distance_category'] = pd.cut(merged_data['distance'], bins=difference_bins, labels=['0-20', '21-100', '101-250', '>250'], right=True)

# Group by 'distance_category' and 'store_id' to calculate the count for each group
merged_data['store_id_count'] = merged_data.groupby(['distance_category', 'store_id'])['campaign_transaction_id'].transform('count')

# Create a new column 'sample_size_category' based on the 'store_id_count' and bins for sample sizes
merged_data['sample_size_category'] = pd.cut(merged_data['store_id_count'], bins=sample_bins, labels=['1-5', '6-10', '11-20', '21-50', '50-200'], right=True)

# Create the cross table without calculating percentages
cross_table_count = pd.crosstab(merged_data['sample_size_category'], merged_data['distance_category'], margins=True, margins_name='Total')

print("Cross Table counts:")
print(cross_table_count)


My expected  cross table is here, I create it manually.
| sample_size_category | 0-20 | 21-100 | 101-250 | >250 | Grand Total |
|----------------------|------|--------|---------|------|-------------|
| 1-5                  | 3    | 3      | 5       | 4    | 15          |
| 6-10                 | 2    | 1      |         |      | 3           |
| Grand Total          | 5    | 4      | 5       | 4    | 18          |

But my output is,
| sample_size_category | 101-250 | >250 | Total |
|----------------------|---------|------|-------|
| 1-5                  | 2       | 9    | 11    |
| Total                | 2       | 9    | 11    |


